# Install android-sdk from official packages

Tags: apt, 16.04, android, android-sdk

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and trying to set up a cordova build environment.
I need Android-SDK for building locally android apps (only the sdk, not android studio). Since 16.04 there are the packages `android` and `android-sdk` in the official Ubuntu repositories. I installed both but couldn't manage to get it work. Are these packages not enough? Where is the android binary? I could install this via getting the packages with wget from google, but getting updates via apt is much nicer.
Isn't this possible?

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: ANDOID_HOME isn't set. I tried `export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk` but actually I coundn't find any android binary package there, so this doesn't work either. I hoped apt would handle setting PATH correctly, but it looks like there is no binary or I do not know where it is installed. I looked at launchpad and it seems this is a meta package. I don't really know what this means though... https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/android-sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried that package as well, same result.

I suspect the SDK-Manager is not included on purpose though.

If you think about it, the SDK-Manager does update stuff like platform-tools and build-tools, and those are provided (and thus updated) by the package via apt.

So I guess the package is intended to be used as-is, without the SDK-Manager so the user cannot mess things up.

For what it's worth, using the package does not make sense for me, and I'll stick to the old-fashioned way, e.g. manual download and installation of the SDK. Mainly because I prefer fine-grained control over the SDK.